# Output1 Error due Python ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Tags: python-3.x

I have been trying to obtain data from a few cli commands into a server platform (splunk) which at this moment is working fine, however after a few minutes I can see this error:

```
**print(output1)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.**
```

Below is my code, keep in mind the imports and the file names are properly configured; I just want to know how can I fix this error on my code:

```
for host in ip_add_file:
    host = host.strip()
    device = ConnectHandler(device_type=platform, ip=host, username=username, password=password)
    output = device.send_command('terminal length 0')
    output = device.send_command('enable') #Editable to be what ever is needed
    output1 = device.send_command('sh run | inc hostname', max_loops= 150,  delay_factor=1)
    output1 = output1.split(' ')
    output1 = output1[1]
    print(output1)
    output2 = device.send_command('sh run | inc mwifi', max_loops= 150,  delay_factor=1)
    print(output2)
    output3 = device.send_command('sh wireless wlan summary | inc mwifi', max_loops= 150,  delay_factor=1)
    print(output3) 
    my_dictionary= {'mydevice': host, 'hostname' : output1, 'cli_mwifi' : output2, 'output_mwifi' : output3 }
    log.info('mwifi_data',  extra = my_dictionary )
```